# How do I style form results posted to a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple form that is supposed to take the input name and write it with a message as a kind of congratulations. The form seems to be working and the results are written to a page but I can't style it without what feels like a really ugly use of css that only allows styles on the text(no setting background, text-align center, etc.).

This will be used offline, so ajax won't work. I was hoping it could be done with vanilla js or maybe jquery. None of the ways the documentation says to style javascript seem to work.

```js
function results() {
  var name= document.getElementById('name').value;

  document.write ("<h1 style='text-align: center;font-family: sans-serif;margin-top: 3em;margin-left: 20px;font-size: 72px;'>Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard</h1>");
  document.write ("<span style='font-family: sans-serif;padding-left: 30%;font-size: 72px;'> "+ name +" </span>");
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return results();" method="post">
    <h3>Enter Name</h3>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Enter" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Just set up CSS classes on the page ahead of time and then give the new HTML elements that will be generated those classes. But really, you should get away from `document.write()` and just create the elements that you know you are going to want and style them with classes, but hide those elements by default. Then, you just unhide them when the form submits.

Comment: I tried doing a style block and calling the class but that caused the page to break.

Comment: You tagged this with `jquery` but it doesn't seem like you are actually using it.

Answer (score 2):

**Just set up CSS classes on the page ahead of time and then give the new HTML elements that will be generated those classes.**

But really, you should get away from `document.write()` and just create the elements that you know you are going to want and style them with classes, but hide those elements by default. Then, you just unhide them when the form submits.

Your code uses syntax and patterns that (unfortunately) won't die the death they should have over 20 years ago. We really don't mix our JavaScript and HTML anymore and we try very hard to remove our CSS from our HTML as well. We keep the 3 languages separate. You'll see that in the code below.

Lastly, since your not actually submitting the data to a server and just using it locally on the same page that you collected it on, you really shouldn't be using the `submit` event and instead use the `click` event of a regular `button`.

```js
// Get references to the HTML elements you'll want to work with
// outside of the callback function so you don't have to scan the
// document for them every time the function runs.

// Also, name is a property of the window object... It's a best-
// practice not to name things name to avoid conflicts.
let form = document.querySelector("form");
let btn = document.getElementById("submit");
let userName = document.getElementById('name');
let results = document.querySelector(".results");
let span = document.querySelector(".results > span");

// Don't set up your event handling in HTML. Do it in JavaScript
btn.addEventListener("click", showResults);

function showResults() {
  span.textContent = userName.value;
  results.classList.remove("hidden");  // Unhide the section
  form.classList.add("hidden");  // And hide the form
}
```

```css
/* We can make a regular tag look like a heading without it being one: */
.questionTitle { font-weight:bold; }

/* Hide the results section by default */
.hidden { display:none; }

/* These classes will style the elements in the results */
.results > h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 72px;
}

.results > span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-left: 30%;
  font-size: 72px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <!--
      Don't use HTML tags because of the way they get formatted on
      the page (i.e. <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, etc.). Use tags because of the
      meaning they convey about the data. Then, style them any way you
      want with CSS.
    -->
    <p class="questionTitle">Enter Name</p>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Enter">
</form>

<section class="results hidden">
  <h1>Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard</h1>
  <span></span>
</section>
```

Comment: it should be `>` rather than `<` in your CSS.

Comment: @Turnip Thanks. Dyslexia kicking in!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using `document.write` there is the option to just write the style out before the two elements you are already writing

Below is an example of that: [I made the styles as ugly as I could for example purpose]

```js
const style = `
  <style type='text/css'>
    h1{
      text-decoration: underline;
      text-decoration: italic;
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    span{
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: red;
      color: yellow;
      font-size: larger;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      transform: scale(1, -1);
    }
  </style>
`;

function results() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  document.write(style);
  document.write("<h1>Swab barque interloper chantey doubloon starboard</h1>");
  document.write("<span> " + name + " </span>");
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return results();" method="post">
  <h3>Enter Name</h3>
  <input id="name" type="text" name="name" />
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

That being said I would recommend creating the elements and styles ahead of time and simply toggling element visibility and replacing dynamic content where required.

Comment: Why not just create the actual `<style>` element ahead of time? There's nothing dynamic about it, so creating a string that you just write to the HTML parser doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't disagree @ScottMarcus, I just fit an answer into the structure already provided.  Given the option I would personally code it like your answer.

Comment: I hear you and I get it, but you should mention that in your answer. When we see folks that are obviously new and using obviously bad/wrong techniques, it's because no one has told them otherwise. I personally feel that we should be nipping these bad habits in the bud or we'll never stop seeing this kind of code.

Comment: Thank you! I created a .css file, added the styles you provided and call the file in the head of the html file. I dumped the javascript into a .js file and call that into the html as well. It seems to be working and is much easier to understand which code I'm working with when adjusting and playing with styles.